# What's the difference between principles of useLibrary and compile files('') in build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, android-uselibrary, android-apache-legacy

After Android 6.0 releases,  Support for the **Apache HTTP client** is removed. If our app is using this client and targets **Android 2.3 (API level 9) or higher**, `HttpURLConnection` class is recommended. It's said that this API is more efficient because it reduces network use through transparent compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption. If we want to continue using the **Apache HTTP API**s, you must first declare the following compile-time dependency in our `build.gradl`e file:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

The legacy jar is in **Android SDK**, whose path is `sdk/platforms/android-23/optional/`. So, it is nearly independent. Meanwhile, this apache legacy jar is putted into `optional/` in Android SDK, so what is `optional/`? What does that mean?

Also we know, we can put this jar into `libs` and then declare it in our `build.gradle` file like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
}
```

Both methods worked as expected when I tested.

But why?

What's the difference between `useLibrary` and `compile files('')` in `build.gradle`? Only because the legacy jar file is in android SDK so I can declare `useLibrary` in `build.gradle`to use it? Could I use other jars in this way?

Could somebody provide some ideas about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`useLibrary` adds the library to classpath while compiling but does not bundle the library with the application.

`compile` dependencies are in classpath at compile time and additionally they get shipped with your APK.

For the Apache HttpClient support, use `useLibrary` when compiling with SDK 23+. The library is already there in the target platform. It is just not there in the compile SDK.

Comment: What do you mean by `The library is already there in the target platform`? If my `targetSDK` is 23+, is it so?

Comment: It's there in the libraries preinstalled on your device. TargetSDK controls what backwards compatibility modes are enabled, not what libraries are installed.

Comment: So, libraries pre-installed in devices and Android SDK we develop on are not the same thing? Could you describe in more details?

Comment: If you have a look at the SDK android.jar you compile with, it's all just stubs throwing exceptions. It's not the same in a runtime environment.