# What is the purpose of useLibrary 'android.test.base' for android testing

Tags: android

In the [official android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project), it says add `useLibrary` for the various dependency.

[image: screenshot]

I realized as long as i have

```
testImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0"
```

in my `dependencies` block, i can still run unit test without any `useLibrary` lines.

### Having `useLibrary` lines or not does not seem to have any effect on being able to run unit/instrumentation test

**Question**: What is the purpose of `useLibrary` lines if i can still run unit/instrumentation tests without it.

---

This question is **NOT** a duplicate of [What's the difference between principles of useLibrary and compile files('') in build.gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014306/whats-the-difference-between-principles-of-uselibrary-and-compile-files-in)

because i am using `testImplementation` keyword instead of `compile` and my question is regarding testing which doesn't actually ship the dependencies with the application.